# is it possible to change hash("ripemd128", $password) to use password_verify($password, $hashed_password)

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption, change-password

Am working on a project that was written around 12 years ago and that is been used by over 5 thousand users. In the registration page `hash("ripemd128","$password")` was used to encrypt the password and in the login page, the same function was also used. Now am thinking of changing the `hash("ripemd128","$password")` in the login page to `password_verify()` and I don't know if is going to work or is it possible to update the password of every user to use the php `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`, then change the `hash("ripemd128","$password")` to `password_verify()` function in the login script.

Also, I don't know if `hash("ripemd128","$password")` is really safe to use on the web now a days(here am talking about security i.e how hard is going to be for malicious users to be able to crack the password)

Comment: You can do the same as you would for upgrading passwords made in password_hash. On login check if the hash is of the old type. If it is then validate the users credentials, if they are valid then create a new hash using password_hash, store it to the db and continue to log in the user. Or you could remove all passwords and force every user to create a new password hash.

Comment: 1. ripemd doesn't seem to have a form compatible with `crypt()`, so it's not going to work with the `password_*()` functions that are built around it. 2. You're right, ripemd is *not* a good idea for hashing passwords.